# How to copy a video to clipboard from the CLI?

Tags: linux, command-line, clipboard

How can I copy videos (like mp4's or mkv's) to the clipboard (like how file managers do it) from the command line? I am using the following:

- **OS**: Manjaro Linux x86_64
- **Kernel**: 5.2.21-1-MANJARO
- **Windows Manager**: AwesomeWM

Both `xclip` and `copyq` didnt work… I tried many different variations but nothing worked:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t video/mp4 -i output.mp4
cat output.mp4 | xclip -i -selection clipboard
xclip -sel clip output.mp4
copyq write video/mp4 - < output.mp4 && copyq select 0
```

I know its not `xclip` or `copyq` thats broken because it copies images and text just fine. I just cant figure out how to copy a video.